# open_basedir restriction warning when the path has already been added to the php.ini directives

Tags: php, windows, iis, drive

So, I'm confused.  This is my error.

```
Warning: scandir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(\{ip address}\Docs) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\inetPub;\\{ip address}\Docs) in C:\inetpub\apps.hnewbie.com\Docs\test.php on line 9

Warning: scandir(\{ip address}\Docs): failed to open dir: Operation not permitted in C:\inetpub\apps.hnewbie.com\Docs\test.php on line 9

Warning: scandir(): (errno 1): Operation not permitted in C:\inetpub\apps.hnewbie.com\Docs\test.php on line 9
```

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51142542/php-upload-read-files-on-separate-drive) originally, using the drive letter (S:) and the full path. I got the open_basedir restriction warning, so I added the the S:\ drive full path to the open_basedir directive in the php.ini. Restarted the IIS server, but the above error persisted. So I thought I would change the letter drive to the IP address in both the php.ini and in my code, to see if that made a difference.  It did not.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


//ini_get('open_basedir');
$dir = "\\{ip address}\Docs";
$ffs = scandir($dir);
?>
```

So I'm not sure what to do next.  I changed the permission on the S:\ drive aka {ip address} to Everyone group.  I still get the warning.  Are there any other additional steps that I can take to get my PHP application to read the drive (it's a network mapped drive, btw)?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260991/php-is-dir-returns-false-on-windows-network-drive/13261159#13261159 `$dir = "\\\\{ip address}\\Docs";`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for linking to that question.   I appreciate it.  I followed your suggestion, but I get this error instead: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. (code: 1326).  I understand that it's an unknown username and password, but what is it referring to?